# Updating to font awesome 5 in backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I see [laravel-backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/) comes with font awesome 4.

I would like to update it to font-awesome 5. But I can't find the file where I must change it.

Has anybody updated font-awesome to v5?